# OpenERP - Why is method write() called after create() when new record is to be created?

Tags: odoo

In the class product_product I have overriden `create()` and `write()` methods. But when I create new product, `create()` is called as well as `write()`. My understanding is that only `create()` should be called. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
class product_product(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        default_code = vals.get('default_code')
        categ_id = vals.get('categ_id')
        class_number = self.pool.get('product.category').browse(cr, uid, categ_id, context=context).x_category_code 
        item_number_validation_check(default_code, class_number)   
        # If default_code already exist, raise error
        pp_obj = self.pool.get('product.product')
        id_s = pp_obj.search(cr, uid,  [('default_code', '=', default_code)])
        if len(id_s) != 0:
            raise osv.except_osv(('Error!'), ('The item number already exists!' ) )
        return super(product_product, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)

    def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
        new_default_code = vals.get('default_code')
```

Comment: Side note: you should add a SQL level unique constraint on default_code rather than doing the check there. 

You assumption seems correct. However, it really depends on the instance and the installed modules. For instance, there could be another addon in the instance which overrides create and calls write. To better understand you need to post the stack trace when you reach the call to your implementation of write().

Comment: any solution @Nebojsa?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, and as you say, the write method should not be called on product creation.

In this case, I think that the better you could do is put a debugger breakpoint in your create method and from there enter in the father's create, to see whether it is calling the write().

And also an additional note, I am pretty sure that in the write you should also put a call to super().